# vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot

Tags: linux, ftp, chroot, vsftpd, write

I want to setup a anonymous only ftp server (able to upload files). Here is my config file:

```
listen=YES

anonymous_enable=YES
anon_root=/var/www/ftp

local_enable=YES
write_enable=YESr.

anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES

xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES

chroot_local_user=YES

dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
pam_service_name=vsftpd
```

But when i try to connect it:

```
kan@kan:~$ ftp yxxxng.bej
Connected to yxxx.
220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)
Name (yxxxg.bej:kan): anonymous
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
Login failed
Can anyone help ?
```

Comment: It has already been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102996/vsftpd-refusing-to-run-with-writable-root-inside-chroot

Answer (score 6):

either do the both other answers (downgrading, or reducing security by disabling the check)

Another option would be to actually fix the issue by having correct permissions for the root chroot folder.

Qouting a nice blogpost, which Marek already linked

> – Add stronger checks for the configuration error of running with a writeable
>   root directory inside a chroot(). This may bite people who carelessly turned
>   on chroot_local_user but such is life.

the chrooted root directory is writeable by the user, this is not allowed anymore by the update Marek mentioned.

So fixing it would require you to:

Change the write permissions of the chrooted home root

f.e.

```
chmod a-w /home/user
```

forcing your users to upload to a subdirectory though.

Answer (score 1):

Change vsftpd to lower version. This is a security patch introduced in vsftpd 2.3.5

http://www.benscobie.com/fixing-500-oops-vsftpd-refusing-to-run-with-writable-root-inside-chroot/

Answer (score 1):

Your `write enable` is set to `YESr` instead of `YES` also try adding

`allow_writeable_chroot=YES`

Usually this helps

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thefrontiergroup/vsftpd`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install vsftpd`

Answer (score 0):

Try either allow_writeable_chroot=YES
 or allow_writable_chroot=YES
in your config,

if that doesn't work, downgrade.

Comment: > if that doesn't work, downgrade.

This is a good point.

Answer (score 0):

The trick for me was to ensure the 'homedir' is not writable for the users in question, put

```
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
```

and comment out

```
#chroot_local_user=YES
```

Not that `chroot_local_user` is listed twice in the 3.0.3 standard /etc/vsftpd.conf file.  That tripped me up.